# Return Bytes Array as HttpResonse with Image/png content type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I want to get an Image from some path, convert it into bytes and return it to the view to display it.

I have a method that takes Image-name/extension and gets image from a directory converts into Byte array as below

First I tried to return it as `File` like below

```
public IActionResult getImage(string image)
{
   var fullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\images\\", image);

   FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);

   byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Close();

   return File(fileBytes , "image/png");
}
```

That didn't work for me as it looks for an image in the `Webroot` like "Image/Image-name.png"

I then tried to write it via `HttpResponseMessage` as below

```
public HttpResponseMessage getImage(string image)
{
   var fullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\images\\", image);

   FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);

   byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Close();

   HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
   result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

   return result;
}
```

I get below response when I tested it on postman
[image]

And here is my razor view

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("getImage", "Image", new{ image=Model.Image})" />
```

The optimal solution is to return it as `HttpResponse` and use it in the razor view

Comment: _"That didn't work for me."_ - how EXACTLY it has not worked for you? Has it thrown an error? It did not return anything?

Comment: yes, it looks an Image in the Webroot directory(localhost<port num> for Image/Image-name.png whhich will return obviously will 404

Comment: Why are you converting it into bytes?

Answer (score 1):

`byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];` will just create an empty array of corresponding size, to use this approach you will need to copy stream contents for example:

```cs
public IActionResult getImage(string image)
{
    var fullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\images\\", image);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);

    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
    fs.Close();

    return File(ms.ToArray() , "image/png", "download.png");
}
```

Note that `File` has an overload accepting virtual path to file (i.e. relative to the app, so it will not work with `C:\images`) also you should consider using [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or `PhysicalFile`.

Comment: I was extending  **API** from an existing Project and I wanted it be Separate Project, So I thought of uploading/serving files (images, pdf, etc.) from an outside directory from both projects, that way I don't have to point the **API** to look files from the web app's Webroot.  for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can remove code and accomplish your task efficiently :

```
public IActionResult getImage(string image)
{
   var fullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\images\\", image);

   return PhysicalFile(fullPath, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: I didn't wanted to return the Physical file, exposing it's path(url), besides asp.net core has  security/policy problem with that, you'll have to configure the `StaticFiles()` middleware to allow outside Webroot path files

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What do you think this is doing that your code isn't doing security wise?

Comment: away to read the image from the directory into Fieldstream/etc. and return/write it as `HttpResponse` with content type of `image/png`. Docker compatibility is also another thing to consider

Comment: I guess I don’t understand why you need the full file in memory to do that. My code sample doesn’t need to read the entire file in memory as a byte[] to accomplish that