# Upload and read files into and from a shared folder in ASP.NET Core with Docker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

A while a go I asked [This quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762101/return-bytes-array-as-httpresonse-with-image-png-content-type/76766394?noredirect=1#comment135798432_76766394) and I kinda paused docker for a while, Now I'm back to it.

Basically, I have 2 ASP.NET Core projects (web app MVC and Web API). Both projects implement files/images upload functionality and the Web API uses some of the files/images uploaded in the web app, hence I want to upload the files/images in a shared folder outside the `webroot` path of the projects (it could be anywhere - it has to support docker in both Windows and Linux). Also the shared folder will contain subfolders (if it has any effect).

The folder/subfolders may look something like this:

```
    FileImages
        images
             users
             products
        files
             pdf
             csv
```

I created a sample project for this which is on GitHub at [here](https://github.com/abdiaa77/FileMS.git)

My problem now is the images I upload are not persisted between container restarts, it probably has to do some with the `docker-compose` file or the way I'm uploading.

Here is my `DockerFile` for the web app (Web API is also the same structure). My dev machine is Windows (with Docker on wsl2) and I will be hosting it on `VPS` running on `Ubuntu 22`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FileWeb/FileWeb.csproj", "FileWeb/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FileWeb/FileWeb.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FileWeb"
RUN dotnet build "FileWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FileWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FileWeb.dll"]
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.4'
networks:
  fileNet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  file_db:
    image: mysql:8.1
    container_name: file_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=file_db
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - fileVolume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - fileNet
    restart: unless-stopped

  file_api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}file_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FileApi/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://*:5001
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
      - "ConnectionStrings__fileDbConnStr=server=file_db;port=3306;database=file_db;user=root;password=root;"
    networks:
      - fileNet
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - fileVolume:/var/lib/app
    depends_on:
      - file_db
    restart: unless-stopped

  file_web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}file_web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FileWeb/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://*:3001
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:3000
      - "ConnectionStrings__fileDbConnStr=server=file_db;port=3306;database=file_db;user=root;password=root;"
    networks:
      - fileNet
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - fileVolume:/var/lib/app
    depends_on:
      - file_db
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  phpMyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=file_db
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - fileNet
    depends_on:
      - file_db
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  fileVolume:
```

Here is the upload method:

```
public string UploadFile(IFormFile? file)
{
    var rootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

    var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "FileImages");

    if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
    }

    String uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file!.FileName;
    string FilePath = Path.Combine(fullPath, uniqueFileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        file.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    return uniqueFileName;
}
```

And finally here is the method that returns the image (from previous question):

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetImage(string image)
{
    var rootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

    var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "FileImages", image);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);

    if (fs == null) 
        return NotFound("Couldn't find requested Image");

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();

    fs.CopyTo(ms);
    fs.Close();

    return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? and any better way to achieve this. also it would be better if the image could be returned as HTTP response or something of that sort.

Comment: I see a couple of issues right off the bat.... first you should not be putting stuff in the user profile folder. Second if you want to persist stuff across restarts of docker you need a persistent volume to put them on like the /var/lib/app folder that you seem to be creating in your yaml file.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8412 .Shouldn't it be fixed? As it only happen on WSL. You may want to mount the volumn from windows file system by `-v /mnt/c` (Although it is not recommanded to mount windows directory to docker https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wsl/best-practices/)

Comment: Ok is there away to solve it in the VPS linux server at least? bearing in mind that I'm building the docker images locally(i.e using windows 11 & wsl2) and the release 'OS` of the images is Linux